# A way to visualize extra compact dimensions

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, compactification, kaluza-klein

I'm wondering if it's valid to think of the meaning of compact dimensions in this way:

Suppose a world with two dimensions and a potential $V(x,y)=\kappa\delta(y)$

Then solving the Schrodinger equation in the $y$ direction results in $exp(-\kappa|y|)$.

Given that $\kappa$ can be tuned so that the width of the wave function can decrease arbitrarily, can one claim that the width of the wavefunction represents $\pi D\sim \kappa$ where $D$ is the diameter of the extra compact dimension?

In this way, the extra dimensions would be large but effectively small and tunneling through them would be almost impossible unless at very high energies.

Comment: Here the $y$ dimension still extends from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ (and the wavefunction is still nonzero, out to infinity). Compact dimensions have a finite size. To me, this is a significant distinction.

Comment: I see, but if u notice the effective(modeled) size of the extra dimension is to a high precision finite. @Ghoster

Comment: @Ghoster Even more, one can think of compact support solutions of schrodinger equation with a proper choice of potential